# AlivePDF generate pdf with grid, text not showing

Tags: actionscript-3, pdf, air, alivepdf

Adding text to a grid in flex
adding the grid to a pdf with some other elements on there as well.

text is not showing up in some cases. I've tested myself silly on the computers i own but there doesnt seem to be a problem.

However, the person i made this for keeps saying text doesnt show up. I've seen the results of his instance of this tool and the keen, trained eye suggests that every row gets stretched out to the bottom (and beyond) of the page. A select all copy paste into plain text app suggests there is no text in the pdf (except for the text that IS showing up)

Anyone had a similar experience? Or any ideas what this problem could be?

Thanks in advance for reading my end-of-all-hopes rant.

Regards

Me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure everyone is using Flash Player 10+

Answer (score 0):

Also you might try running IE 8 with quirks mode turned on or set the tag to emulate IE 7.

```
 <meta  http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```